# Spring Boot application should start even though Cassandra database is down

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

I have implemented a spring boot oAuth application which runs on Tomcat server and uses Cassandra as database. When the database server is up and running the application gets deployed and runs fine. The problem arises when database is down so my oAuth application also refuses to get deployed. The applications are deployed on different server in production so while my container restarts we cant guarantee the order of server restart.

I have tried many solutions available like

```
//@EnableCassandraRepositories("<My Package>")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Using similar approach in `@SpringBootApplication` class as well. But nothing helped.

The real problem what I guess is that we are using default implementation of Cassandra/Spring in which we have to use repositories. When the application is getting deployed the `@Bean`/`@Autowired` annotations fail and my application.

- The implementation which we are thinking can be as below: The oAuth application should run regardless of Cassandra is down or up.
- If the DB server is down, when first request comes to OAuth it should make a connection, return a new session object and reuse same session object for following requests.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what if the first request comes in and there still isn't an up-and-running database?  You can make beans lazy (on both creation and injection point).

Comment: If request comes and DB is down it's OK we can return failure response but it should check for next requests if session object is null should automatically connect when DB comes up. That's the key change we need.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot? The Cassandra driver 4.x has options to keep reconnecting until it succeeds.

Comment: I am using oAuth 2.0 & Cassandra 3.0 series libraries. I think It's not about Cassandra to try and reconnect but what we want is Spring boot should deploy my application even Cassandra DB is down.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

in application.properties file.

Comment: I added the property but not helpful. I even added @Lazy  from class org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy; on my Cassandra configuration class. But the application is still failing when Cassandra DB is down during startup.